# poweroutage resulted in corrupt wiredtiger database files

Tags: mongodb

Im using mongodb 3.6.5 on debian64 in kvm virtual machines (5 shards).

after a poweroutage today my database files from four shards are corrupt and the mongod instances produce two different errors.

i allready tried "-repair" and the wt-commandline-utility with no success.

please help me, repairing my wiredtiger.wt 's

i allready created a jira-ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36828

kind regards,

michael

Comment: Hi. Got a backup ? as it's your next step sadly

Comment: the good news first: yes, the bad: its a month behind (in my case, processing historical data and generation of statistics, bad) - yes, i need a backup strategy and a ups..